# Multisite for Multisite?

Tags: plugins, multisite

Is there anyway I can allow users to create their own WordPress multisite network on my multisite network? It will be a premium service and will work much like reseller hosting, where the customer will pay the distributor and the remaining goes to the middleman as profit.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no nested aspect to what you are describing, it would be simply multisite once. However in two sentences you include in your question whole industry with challenging commercial features. What answer precisely you are looking for?

Comment: I want to offer a reseller feature where other people can resell multisites on our network. The service will be paid. How do I do this?

Comment: I would assume you start with research into existing solutions, scope of custom development it would take, budget it would cost and developers to implement it. This doesn't seem like something you an get ready-made off the shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to create Networks inside a Multisite Network. And it can be done with:

- #### [Networks+](http://wpebooks.com/networks/)

  > This plugin provides the interface to set up another network of sites within the install you already have. You may choose to run this additional network off a different domain entirely or a subdomain – it’s very flexible.
- #### [WP Multi Network](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/)

  > Adds a Network Management UI for super admins in a WordPress Multisite environment

The second step (out of the scope of a Q&A site) is to inspect these plugins for public functions/methods and hooks to integrate with your custom commerce solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally also have a look at an alternate direction: Use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) to install a separate wp multisite install (codebase wise). I could imagine, that this will be more flexible in handling. But this also depends if you plan to do classical hosting or cloud based hosting. Installation/integration to your order management system will also be pretty easy using wp-cli.